# How to get title from HTTP text representation via Qt?

Tags: qt

Qt 4.7 DOM API seems kind of strange :(. I have a text HTML representation and need to get "title" text. Seems very easy, but following code is not working, i get empty string:

```
QDomDocument dom;
dom.setContent( "<html><head><title>this is a title</title></head></html>" );
QString title = dom.elementsByTagName( "title" ).item( 0 ).nodeValue();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
QString title = dom.elementsByTagName( "title" ).item( 0 ).firstChild().nodeValue();
```

Because the tree structure for text is:
node `<title>`
=> text element